# Template logic not functioning properly

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

template.html

```
<tr><td>
    {% if place %}                                
      <input type="checkbox" id="select_all"/>Display all<br />
      <hr style="width: 150px;margin: 8px 0;">
      {% for value in place %}
      {{ value }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{% include "buttons/addalist.html" %} {% include "buttons/save.html" %}</td></tr>
```

views.py

```
def type_list(request,type_id):
    user = request.user
    try:
        type_list = Types.objects.get(user=user.id, id=type_id)
    except:
        return redirect('incident.views.incident_types')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        report_type = TypeSettingsForm(request.POST)

        if 'title' in request.POST and report_type.is_valid():
            if request.POST['title'].strip():
                result = report_type.save(commit=False)
                result.user = user
                result.is_active = True
                result.parent_type_id = type_id
                result.save()
        else:
            place = TypeSelectionForm(type_id, request.POST)
            if types.is_valid() and 'status' in request.POST:
                types.save(type_id, request.POST)
                type_list.is_active = eval(request.POST['status'])
                type_list.save()

                return redirect('incident.views.incident_types')
    place = TypeSelectionForm(type_id)

    return render(request, 'incident/type_list.html',
        {
            'about_menu': True,
            'type_list': type_list,
            'place':place
    })
```

clicking addalist button,values are getting saved and displayed in template.

But initially,if their is no value displayed from for loop, `Display All` with check box should not come to display.If a single value from for loop is entered Display All with check box will come to display.It's a small logical error but i am not  got this.Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is currently happening? You've told us what should happen, but not what is happening at the moment? I presume that `Display All` is shown even when the there are no values in `place`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable inside views `count_check_boxes` that counts the number of choices the form have and test for it inside your template.

```
def type_list(request,type_id):
    ...
    place = TypeSelectionForm(type_id)
    count_check_boxes = len(place.fields['checkbox_field'].choices)
    return render(request, 'incident/type_list.html',
        {
            'about_menu': True,
            'type_list': type_list,
            'place':place,
            'check_boxes_count':check_boxes_count
    })
```

And in your template:

```
<tr><td>
    {% if place %}                                
      {%if check_boxes_count > 0%}
      <input type="checkbox" id="select_all"/>Display all<br />
      <hr style="width: 150px;margin: 8px 0;">
      {%endif%}
      {% for value in place %}
      {{ value }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{% include "buttons/addalist.html" %} {% include "buttons/save.html" %}</td></tr>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr><td>
    {% if place %}      
        {% for value in place %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
            <input type="checkbox" id="select_all"/>Display all<br />
            <hr style="width: 150px;margin: 8px 0;">
            {% endif %}
            {{ value }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{% include "buttons/addalist.html" %} {% include "buttons/save.html" %}</td></tr>
```

Using `forloop.first` checks if the for loop is in on its first iteration if so it'll only display the input once per entire iteration.

Comment: I tried with your code,still it is displaying the same,If no values from {{values}} is displayed "Display All" with checkbox is dispalying. What i want is if value from {{ value }} is oming for display,Display All should display.

Comment: How does `place` look like? the {% if place %} checks if place has any elements in it.

Comment: What in the `list` place. That's what I want to know.